# Programmatically add constraints to collectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add constraints to my collectionviewcells. But when I use this code in its class I get an console error

```
class IndexD: UICollectionViewCell {

func contstraints() {
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": IndexD.self]))
}
}
```

The error I receive is:

> **unrecognized selector sent to class**

I'm not sure how to change my code to remove any errors. The goal is for me to set the constraint for each specific collectionviewcell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `views` dictionary, you are passing the incorrect value for the view `v0`.  You should be using `self` which refers the current instance of the class instead of `IndexD.self` which refers to the class itself.

Change your `views` to:

```
views: ["v0": self]
```

---

There are other issues as well.  You are adding the generated constraints to `self`, but they need to be added to the higher item in the view hierarchy.  `"H:|[v0]|"` will generate constraints that involve the `superview` of `self`, so you really need to do `superview?.addConstraints(...`.

Since iOS 8, there is an easier way to activate constraints.  You can set their `isActive` property to `true` and they will automatically be added to the proper views.  If you have more than one constraint to activate, then you can call `NSLayoutContraint.activate()` with an array of constraints and iOS will activate all of the constraints.

If you have no `NSLayoutFormatOptions`, just pass `[]`.  And, since this is the default value for that parameter, you can leave `options: []` out altogether.

So taking all of that into account, here is the corrected version of your code:

```
func contstraints() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", metrics: nil, views: ["v0": self]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I run the new code however I get the error **'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|[v0]| **. When removing `|` from the code it runs, but does not create constraints

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in particular?  Since this is a collectionViewCell, you typically do not add constraints to the cells themselves to control their layout.  You can add constraints within them to control the layout of items within the cell.

Comment: Yes you are correct. From further research I believe dynamic cell autoresizing is what I need to use and not constraints.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven't import UIKit you should. And you need to initialize that class so CollectionCell knows where to execute your function. Your code should look like this..

```
import UIKit

class IndexD: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addContstraints()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func addContstraints() {
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": IndexD.self]))
}
```

I changed your method name because when you try to execute it in override init, Swift refers your method as [NsLayoutConstraints] and confuses.